# Passing object conforming to AnyObject protocol into generic requiring AnyObject

Tags: swift, generics

Assuming this code:

```
protocol Test: AnyObject {}
class RealTest: Test {}


class Wrapper<A: AnyObject> {
    weak var value: A?
    init(_ value: A) {
         self.value = value
    }
}

let realTest = RealTest()
let wrapper = Wrapper(realTest)
```

the code above works and wrapper is created. However, when I change the realTest to:

```
let realTest: Test = RealTest()
```

I get the error message

> Generic class 'Wrapper' requires that 'Test' be a class type

Is there a solution to this, as I need the AnyObject requirement and I only know the protocol the objects are conforming to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Protocols do not conform to themselves (or to any protocol). Only concrete types can conform to a protocol.

If the only thing you need to know about this type is that it is a class (AnyObject), then you don't want a generic here, you just want to pass the protocol type itself (technically the "existential").

```
class Wrapper {
    let value: AnyObject
    init(_ value: AnyObject) {
         self.value = value
    }
}
```

If you need a generic here for some other reason, then the generic must be over a concrete type, not a protocol.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your comment. I have over-simplified my code, sry for that. The wrapper holds a weak reference to the value, so I would be nice to have a generic so that I don't need to cast when accessing that value. I have updated the code example to reflect that.

Comment: That's fine, but then the type must be concrete, not a protocol. You cannot have a `Wrapper<Test>`. Swift does not have any way to construct that.

Comment: ok, no way I can make the protocol concrete as I would lose all benefits of having a protocol in the first place. Alright, thanks, I will need to come up with another solution then :)